# Who was the smartest of the Wiggins

Tags: enders-game

To be clear: I'm only referring to John Paul (Father), Theresa (Mother), Peter, Valentine, and Ender. Who has what we would call the highest "[I.Q](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligence_quotient)"? I'd much prefer an official quote from the books or Card, but inference from the books would be interesting too. If possible, try to establish an "order" of intelligence.

Comment: I don't recall a single mention of IQ of any of them in the book. Also bear in mind that Wiggins' talents aren't all pure IQ - e.g. John's special talent was savant-like ability to get people to do what he wanted (Ender inherited that), Ender's was leadership qualities including other things as well as pure tactical and strategic abilities.

Comment: As an aside - all of them are implied to have genius level (160? 180?+) of IQ, and it's well known that in real life IQ tests aren't very well calibrated at the high end.

Answer (score 2):

In *Ender's Game*, Valentine says:

> Ender and I aren't stupid.  We scored as well as you did on
>   everything.  Better on some things.  We're all such wonderfully bright
>   children.  You're not the smartest, Peter, just the biggest.

Peter agrees with her, so it's presumably the truth.  It seems reasonable that the "everything" includes some sort of I.Q. test, so this indicates that Valentine and Ender score better than Peter in an I.Q. test.

(John Paul and Theresa were given permission to have Andrew because Peter was too vicious and Valentine too mild, with Andrew "just right", rather than because of anything to do with intelligence - see the musing by Valentine in [*Xenocide*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0312861877)).

There's not a great deal of information about Ender's parents, even in the [*First Meetings*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/060634330X) stories "The Polish Boy" and "Teacher's Pet".  We know that John Paul scored very highly in leadership, and must have had reasonable intelligence as well, otherwise Captain Rudolf (of IF) wouldn't have been interested in him (and he did graduate with valedictorian honours, after moving to America).  However, the implication is always that it's Ender's ability to understand human (and non-human) nature that was his father's gift.

In "Teacher's Pet" and the Shadow books, we see that Theresa is "a genius researcher in her own right", but there's no measurement specifically; we do know that Ender's (and Peter and Valentine's) maternal grandfather was a "renowned" genius.  The implication is that the children's gift for strategy comes from their mother.

In [*Ender's Homecoming*](http://www.intergalacticmedicineshow.com/cgi-bin/mag.cgi?do=issue&vol=i7&article=_card), John Paul says:

> Theresa, you're the smartest person I know.

And we see the children referred to as "super-geniuses".  So if you want a rank, it would be John Paul, Theresa, Peter, then Andrew and Valentine in some order or perhaps equal.

Comment: You say that Peter is lower than Ender and Valentine, but then you put him before them. Is that a typo? Also your last quote doesn't settle John vs Theresa.

Comment: @ike I'm going low to high. The quote shows JP believes T is smarter than he is, and that's borne out by First Meetings and the Shadow books. It's not explicit, but I don't think you'll get anything explicit.

Comment: But then the parents should be after the children, no? John Paul's statement includes his kids.